# How to create a web proxy service using a Java Program

Tags: java, xml, json, web-services, soap

I have a scenario where I am supposed to contact a RESTFul API which sends me a response in JSON. After I get the response I am suppose to store the data in the DB.

We use BPEL for our development. But, for clean development/deployment I am using Java for contacting the RESTFul API so that I don't have to handle any Java codes in my BPEL. So I wanted to create a web service proxy.

I have created a class which contacts this endpoint and gets me the response (JSON) and converts the response message(JSON) into XML.

Now, I want to create a Web Proxy service which I can host for this Java program that I have created. Is there any way that I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I feel what you need is to create a restful service that your BPEL can talk to and which inturn consumes the other restful API. Take a look at http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution to this. I created an intermediate webservice using java (using json.org library) for consuming the REST API and then giving my BPEL the SOAP response after parsing the JSON response.